# x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc: error: unrecognized command line option '--showme:link'; did you mean '--force-link'?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, anaconda3

I am getting the error

`x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc: error: unrecognized command line option '--showme:link'; did you mean '--force-link'?`

whenever I open the new terminal.

I set my anaconda to auto-activate upon the start of the terminal. I don't get this error if I deactivate the anaconda upon start of terminal.

can someone please explain what is going on?

Comment: How exactly do you activate - deactivate Anaconda?  What is the difference in - I assume - your bashrc shell initialization script?

Comment: I used the command  `conda config --set auto-activate-base False` to remove auto-activate. so next time I start a terminal anaconda is not active. I didn't understand the second question. I think problem is related to openmpi.